# PHP - dynamic fields array not

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, dynamic

I have a form with dynamic fields. When I add a dynamic field and do a `var_dump` of that field, I am getting only the first result.

Form:

```
<div class="form-group halltype">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">HallType</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title1[]" placeholder="Main Title"><br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title2[]" placeholder="Title 2"><br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="seating[]" placeholder="Seating Capacity"><br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="floating[]" placeholder="Floating Capacity"><br />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group addhalltype">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">                        
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="">Add Hall Type</button>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".addhalltype").click(function() {
    $halltype = '<div class="form-group halltype"><label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">HallType</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="title1[]" placeholder="Main Title"><br /><input type="text" class="form-control" name="title2[]" placeholder="Title 2"><br /><input type="text" class="form-control" name="seating[]" placeholder="Seating Capacity"><br /><input type="text" class="form-control" name="floating[]" placeholder="Floating Capacity"><br /></div></div>';
    $($halltype).insertBefore(".addhalltype");
});
```

and if I do `var_dump($_POST['title1'])`, I get

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "1212"
}
```

Comment: when using dynamic fields in a form if there are multiple elements you want to return in an array use something like this `name='title[]'` on all the title elements then when you vardump $_POST['title'] you will get an array with all the items

Comment: I am also not seeing a `<form>` element and am also making an assumption that you are posting this "form" to a php page that you are var_dumping / handling the response with

Answer (score 0):

you are printing $_POST['title1'] in var_dump it will show you only value that u inserted for name="title1[]".

Here you are using dynamic array but with different name ie name equal to title1[] title1[] seating[] and floating[].

if you want to get all the post values in one name like title[0],title[1],...title[n] to get the result in this format you have to write your above code with this format.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]" placeholder="Main Title"><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]" placeholder="Title 2"><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]" placeholder="Seating Capacity"><br />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title[]" placeholder="Floating Capacity"><br />
```